# Why is this class member leaving a SQL connection open?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database-connection, connection-pooling

Further to my recent questions, I've now closed most of the connections that our web application was leaving open. However, the connection created by the function below remains open. Can anyone identify why it is not closing?

```
public DataTable GetSubDepartment(int deptId)
{   
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Defaults.ConnStr))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_getDepartmentChild", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dptParent", deptId));

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

*** EDIT *** 
Following @HenkHolterman's comment:
I'm using SQL Server Management Studio Activity log to view the open connections. This one is listed as sleeping. SO what you say makes sense. Is there any way I can tell that this is a pooled connection rather than an open one?

Comment: Are you sure? Both the `using` and `Fill()` should be closing it. You're probably looking at connections in the Pool, nothing to do with this code.

Comment: You can tell when filling the next Table does not add an _extra_ connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably because it went back to the connection pool.

Call

```
SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
```

to clear the pool, then it should disappear. This could sometimes be useful, but is usually not needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that it's hanging in the [connectionpool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28VS.80%29.aspx)